# Name function, and call it in HTML?

Tags: jquery, function

I have a script like below, and I'd like to 'name' it, and then call it in my HTML, like so:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <script>loadLibrary()</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$.getJSON(accountProjects, function(data) {
   //Do stuff....
});
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Wrap the JS code around the function and then call it

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that?

Comment: To call the getJSON, `function loadLibrary() { $.getJSON(accountProjects, function(data) {
   //Do stuff....
}); }`

Comment: Thank you. Simpler than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution -

```js
function loadLibrary() {
  alert("write below");
  $.getJSON(accountProjects, function(data) {
   //Do stuff....
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadLibrary();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">loadLibrary()</script>
     
   </body>
</html>
```